# Is there a fax daemon I can install on a remote machine and use over the internet?

Tags: networking, remote-access, dd-wrt, fax

Here's the situation: As a poor student I currently don't have a phone line and so obviously no fax capabilities. However my parents have a phone line and a fax machine (One of those HP combo machines [with a fixed ip]). I've also set them up with a router running DD-WRT.

I was wondering if there is some sort of daemon, preferably with a web interface that I can install locally on my parent's network, that can accept files from me, and fax them automatically through their fax.

If nothing like that exists, do you have another solution? (not involving 3rd party websites)

Thanks.